# как сохранять изменения input при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, python

У меня есть сайт, обычный кликер для webapp telegram
Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки которая увеличивает value input на 1 значение, сохраняло изменения input в LocalStorage. Мне это нужно чтобы при обновлении страницы, input сохранял значение и пользоватеель мог дальше кликать до определенного прогресса.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    width: 420px;
    height: 740px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}


.item {
    text-align: center;
    width: 418px;
    height: 700px;
    background: rgb(239 239 239);
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.usercard {
    text-align: center;
}

.barmenu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 45px;
  background: rgb(239 239 239);
}

.btn-menu {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="item">
                <input id="number-diet" class="js-number" type="number" name="number" value="1" readonly>
                <br>
                <button class="btn" id="btn1"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="barmenu">
                <button class="btn-menu">Друзья</button>
                <button class="btn-menu">Рейтинг</button>
                <button class="btn-menu">Задания</button>
                <button class="btn-menu">Бусты</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>function countFunc(count) {
        var btnPlus = count.querySelector('.btn');
        var field = count.querySelector('.js-number');
        var fieldValue = parseFloat(field.value, 10);
    
        btnPlus.addEventListener('click', function() {
            fieldValue++;
            field.value = fieldValue;
          });
    }
    
    var counts = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
    counts.forEach(countFunc);</script>
    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что надо понятно, что не получилось?

Comment: не получилось сделать так чтобы сайт сохранял значения накликанные пользователем

Comment: Опишите более подробно что вам нужно можно хранить инфу в локал сторедже или в куках. Если нужно чтобы информация подтягивалась для всех пользователей можно подключить бд или создать json и перезаписывать его